Wt on Apache2 with mod_fcgid configuration throwing error
Throwing error when browsing hello.wt
Ubuntu distribution:
Distributor ID: Neon
Description:    KDE neon 6.0
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

Apache2 version
Server version: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2024-07-17T18:57:26

Appche2 Error snippet
[2024-Aug-12 02:41:43.736] 29974 - [info] "WServer/wthttp: fatal: Document root (--docroot) was not set."
[Mon Aug 12 02:41:43.737088 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 29910:tid 139722038322752] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 127.0.0.1:36194] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Mon Aug 12 02:41:43.737218 2024] [core:error] [pid 29910:tid 139722038322752] [client 127.0.0.1:36194] End of script output before headers: hello.wt

contents of the fcgi.conf
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
            AddHandler fcgid-script .wt
            FcgidIPCDir /var/lib/apache2/fcgid
            FcgidIdleTimeout 100
            FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 1
            FcgidInitialEnv WT_DOC_ROOT=/var/www/wt/
            DocumentRoot /var/www/wt
    
            <Directory /hello/hello.wt>
               Options +ExecCGI -Indexes
               FcgidWrapper "/var/www/wt/examples/hello/hello.wt --docroot=."
               Require all granted
            </Directory>
    
            <IfModule mod_mime.c>
               AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
            </IfModule>
</IfModule>

contents of my site config
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin thomas@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wt/
    ServerName wt.example.com

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/wt/
    <Directory "/var/www/wt">
       Options +ExecCGI -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
       Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

Not much documentation on this, and seems I've gotten pretty far in this; I would not be seeing the error, if the module was not at least getting called. :-)
The crux of this biscuit is --docroot is not being set when executing using mod_fcgid within apache2.
When starting hello.wt from the CLI in terminal, it expects --docroot, as well as --http-listen parameters passed which then starts listening.  The example starts an wthttp instance listening on 0.0.0.0:8080.  This all works, and my C++ code is compiled, and executes correctly in the browser.
The issue is when trying to configure mod_fcgid with the above configuration.  It's still looking for --docroot parameter.  How can I set this within the configuration? or how can I compile the examples to have this preset?
